# Как принять значение переменной из php c помощью json

Tags: json

Вот такой кусочек кода из name.php отправляет строку к исполняемому файлу function.php

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "function.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
//Вот здесь я так понимаю должна быть функция принимающая данные
//Должно быть так 
//var country = (country1,country2,country3)

}
});
```

а вот php

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
....
{
foreach ($arr as $value) {                  
$spisok .= $value.',';              
}  
echo ('('.$spisok.')');
```

Данные приходят (судя по firebug), но как их установить в переменную JS?

Comment: Ну, в function.php сделай: `echo json_encode('('.$spisok.')');`

и в success: function(html)

    {
       var country = html;
    }

Comment: Что то с помощью json_encode у меня отправляет NULL :(

Comment: Разобрался, убрал iconv(), теперь отправляет, но не принимает. :(

Comment: Проверил alertом, принимает, но почему то переменную не видит скрип который идет далее :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "function.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json', // добавили тип принимаемых данных
    success: function(html)
    {
        // теперь переменная html - это объект (распарсеный JSON)    
    }
});
```